# Install mysql on windows on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, mysql

When I had a job, MySQL was installed on the Linux server and I used to connect using [Xshell](https://www.netsarang.com/products/xsh_overview.html). Now, I want to install it on **Windows 7** and have a good command line interface (better than cmd).

I have not worked much on Windows, but I would like to do the following

- Install MySQL Package
- Access it using command line.

Please help.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/ What's so hard about that?

Comment: Not sure how I missed it. Thanks. How can I connect using Xshell after installing it? Is there any better terminal emulator?

Comment: Never used Xshell but seems it's a terminal emulator. In your case will you have a separate DB server? If you're installing MySQL on your own machine then what's the point of Xshell?

Comment: installing it on my own machine. i don't like cmd.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You want to use a terminal emulator to connect to your own computer? If you don't like cmd then use one of the many cmd alternatives. If you want to use bash or some other shell then install Linux on your system, or perhaps cygwin (but I've never used MySQL through that).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I hate doing MSI installs of MySQL on Windows (See my old post [MySQL quiet installation references wrong executable](https://superuser.com/questions/461953/mysql-quiet-installation-references-wrong-executable/492875#492875) as an example of why)

I highly recommend using the ZIP file that does not require an installation process.

See my following posts

- `Feb 10, 2011` : [Installing isolated instance of MySQL on Windows using silent install with .msi](https://serverfault.com/a/234125/69271) (I wrote up how to Install MySQL in Windows Without using MSI)
- `Oct 28, 2013` : [How do I start a MySQL Server in Windows ?](https://superuser.com/questions/666521/how-do-i-start-a-mysql-server-in-windows/666549#666549)